# see htaccess code

Tags: .htaccess

Was just wondering if someone would be kind enough to look at my htaccess code and tell me if there is anything that looks obviously incorrect. I don't know much about this stuff. Also not sure if the parts should be organize differently or if it is necessary to put 
"RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /"
in there more than once?
Anyways, here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine  on 
RewriteBase    / 

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.shtml$   $1.html [R=301,L] 

redirect 301 /games.html http://www.slimekids.com/games/
redirect 301 /trailers.html http://www.slimekids.com/book-trailers/
redirect 301 /authors.html http://www.slimekids.com/authors/
redirect 301 /reference.html http://www.slimekids.com/reference/
redirect 301 /reviews.html http://www.slimekids.com/book-reviews/
redirect 301 /searches.html http://www.slimekids.com/search-engines/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the domain is not www.slimekids.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.slimekids\.com$ [NC]
#redirect to www.slimekids.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.slimekids.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#leave this rule in place, but after the one above to handle the home page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.slimekids.com/ [R=301,L] 

ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving? What are you trying to do? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I guess I wasn't looking for real specific errors, but I was mostly wondering if there was anything in there that is unnecessary like both of those "RewriteEngine  on 
RewriteBase    / " or if something looks out of order or needs to be in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine.

You are correct that the `RewriteEngine on`, and `RewriteBase /` don't need to be repeated.

I notice the the exprires are quite far into the future. e.g. image expire after one year. Might be that your code uses cachebusting of some kind when something changes.

I would probably slightly alter the lines that remove the `index.html` part from the url, to also work on subfolders (e.g. `/games/index.html`), instead of just the root (`/index.html`)

```
#leave this rule in place, but after the one above to handle the home page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ http://www.slimekids.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey,   Thanks for your response. So does it matter which one of those "RewriteEngine   on RewriteBase /" I take out, or does it not matter where that is placed? Also, I noticed one has the ending slash moved further away. I'm not sure if that matters either.

Comment: In regards to the expires, does this mean that if I change a jpg image, some users might not see the change for a year? Not sure what you mean by cachebusting, but it sounds like you are suggesting shortening the expires. The reason I put this part on there was to improve speed (when I did the google page speed test, it suggested this), but I assume that changing expires from a year to a month won't really make a big difference in that respect.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you meant about altering the lines that remove index.html to also work on subfolders? Why would I need to account for an ending such as /games/index.html?

Comment: Just keep the first. I like to put them before the rewriterules, but I believe it doesn't really matter. Spacing doesn't matter in rewritebase. You are correct about the image not being updated for a year in your example. Switching to a month would more or less be result in the same speed improvement. Kind of risky to just add the rules because some tool says so without understanding it first.

Comment: If google loads the page with url `/games/index.html` it would get the same page as with `/games/` (I presume). Search engines will detect duplicated content an will only index one of those urls. To prevent google from picking the longer/uglier one just redirect it to the short/pretty one.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate your feedback. Just one more thing... In what scenario is it possible for google to load the page with a url such as /games/index.html? I thought that index.html thing was only an issue with the homepage.
Will replacing it with that code that you provided in your initial response, adding the (.*) and the ($1), be the remedy for this issue?

Comment: Is as much of an issue as it is on the homepage. Not real big an issue, but as you had the code for the homepage, why not also include other pages. The edit I made will make word-peace, but it will indeed fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

New and improved htaccess. Hopefully this all looks good now. Thanks very much.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.shtml$   $1.html [R=301,L] 

redirect 301 /games.html http://www.slimekids.com/games/
redirect 301 /trailers.html http://www.slimekids.com/book-trailers/
redirect 301 /authors.html http://www.slimekids.com/authors/
redirect 301 /reference.html http://www.slimekids.com/reference/
redirect 301 /reviews.html http://www.slimekids.com/book-reviews/
redirect 301 /searches.html http://www.slimekids.com/search-engines/

#if the domain is not www.slimekids.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.slimekids\.com$ [NC]
#redirect to www.slimekids.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.slimekids.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#leave this rule in place, but after the one above to handle the home page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ http://www.slimekids.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404page.html

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```